# In the Stargate Movie, what military awards does Jack O'Neil hold?

Tags: stargate, stargate-movie

Based on J. O’Neil’s ribbons in the Stargate **Movie**, what awards did he receive?
[image]

I think, I identified most of them, but could somebody please confirm or correct me where I went wrong – as some of the devices I identified are not used with that particular award.

A1 Bronze Star Medal (*with one bronze star*)
A2 Air Force Commendation Medal
B1 *???*
B2 *Combat Readiness Medal – seems to use Medal colors and not Ribbon colors*
B3 National Defense Service Medal (*with one bronze oak leaf cluster*)
C1 Vietnam Service Medal (*with three bronze oak leaf clusters*)
C2 Southwest Asia Service Medal (*with one bronze star*)
C3 Humanitarian Service Medal
D1 Air Force Longevity Service Award (with three bronze oak leaf clusters)
D2 Air Force Overseas Long Tour Service Ribbon
D3 Air Force Small Arms Expert Marksmanship Ribbon
E1 Air Force Training Ribbon
E2 Vietnam Campaign Medal
E3 Kuwait Liberation Medal (Saudi Arabia)

And of course there is the US Air Force Command Pilot Badge.

WARNING: Once is happenstance. Twice is coincidence. Three times is enemy action. While I am happy that people are helping me by editing the question - could you please stop editing the name. We are talking about the movie here, where the main character is the Colonel O'Neil with only one "L", the one who has no sense of humor at all.

[image]

Comment: Related, not dupe; [In the Stargate TV Series, what military awards does Jack O'Neill hold?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/127319/in-the-stargate-tv-series-what-military-awards-does-jack-oneill-hold)

Comment: Both the novelization and the shooting script identify Colonel "One-L" as a Marine. Did they change that before filming?

Comment: The Vietnam Service Medal gets service stars, not oak leaf clusters. B1 is probably the Air Force Achievement Medal.

Comment: In an attempt to complete the list I shot [a couple of GIFs](https://imgur.com/a/WxzD34x), but they're probably no better than the picture you already got and didn't get me anywhere. Those are all from the scene where O'Neil notifies the team the project is now classified, right after Daniel wipes the floor with their poor translation of the symbols (roughly 15m in).