# In the Stargate TV Series, what military awards does Jack O'Neill hold?

Tags: stargate, stargate-sg1

In the Stargate film, Jack seems to be wearing a different range of military awards and decorations than he does in the TV Series.

Based on the TV Show **only**, what awards and decorations does General Jack O'Neill hold?

[image: Jack wearing a lot of military awards]

Comment: Related, not dupe; [In the Stargate Movie, what military awards does Jack O'Neil hold?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/127281/in-the-stargate-movie-what-military-awards-does-jack-oneil-hold)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I would like to expand on Richard's answer, as there various Ribbon props used over the series.
[image: Various ribbons throughout the series]
[image: Colonel Jack O'Neill service ribbons]

[Source](http://www.yuchtar.com/Ribbons.html)

Better view:

[image: cloth version of the above]
[image: another cloth version]

And also these hanging on his office wall (as Commander of SGC).
[image: Medals pinned to a wall]

[Source](http://www.stargate-sg1-solutions.com/wiki/Jack_O'Neill:_Military_Career)

This means that we have the following confirmed:

> Defense Distinguished Service Medal
>   Air Force Distinguished Service Medal
>   Silver Star
>   Defense Superior Service Medal
>   Airman's Medal
>   Purple Heart
>   Defense Meritorious Service Medal
>   Meritorious Service Medal (with three bronze oak leaf clusters)
>   Air Medal (with two bronze oak leaf clusters)
>   Aerial Achievement Medal
>   Joint Service Commendation Medal
>   Air Force Commendation Medal (with two bronze oak leaf clusters)
>   Air Force Achievement Medal (with two bronze oak leaf clusters)
>   Air Force Outstanding Unit Award (with three bronze oak leaf clusters and V Device)
>   Air Force Organizational Excellence Award
>   Combat Readiness Medal (with one bronze oak leaf cluster)
>   National Defense Service Medal (with bronze service star)
>   Vietnam Service Medal
>   Southwest Asia Service Medal (with bronze service star)
>   Air Force Overseas Long Tour Service Ribbon
>   Air Force Longevity Service Award (with three bronze oak leaf clusters)
>   Air Force Small Arms Expert Marksmanship Ribbon (with bronze service star)
>   Air Force Training Ribbon
>   Vietnam Campaign Medal
>   Kuwait Liberation Medal (Saudi Arabia)

However I cannot identify this one:
[image: star-shaped medal with red ribbon]

In addition [this wiki](http://www.stargate-sg1-solutions.com/wiki/Jack_O'Neill:_Military_Career) claims that he also owns:

> Air Force Cross Medal
>   Bronze Star Medal

But I am unsure of the evidence.

Last but not least, based on the above and his service he also ought to own:

> *Air Force Good Conduct Medal*
>   *Prisoner of War Medal*
>   *Armed Forces Expeditionary Medal*
>   *Kuwait Liberation Medal (Kuwait)*

Comment: You have my +1 for this. MIssing one though :-P

Comment: That appears to be a Bronze Star; http://www.vspa.com/usaf-medals.htm

Comment: @Richard: I am leaning that way too, but I still feel is 50/50 about it. The one displayed seems to be red-gold, while the bronze star is red-blue-white. It truly just may be an optical illusion, but I keep wondering if it is not an foreign medal. This particular prop and also the Purple heart prop were not listed for sale.

Comment: It seems to be the colour-bleed from the red making it look gold.

Comment: I agree, this is a bronze star with oak leaf cluster.

Comment: It should be noted that the medals on the wall, *that Jack was never seen wearing* are not necessarily his.  They could have been a relative's or close friend's.

Comment: @RBarryYoung: Well, he did wear 5 of 8: Kuwait Liberation Medal (Saudi Arabia), Southwest Asia Service Medal; Air Force Distinguished Service Medal, Air Medal, National Defense Service Medal

Comment: @RBarryYoung Oak leaf cluster is usually attached to the ribbon, no?  It's not that shape either.  I'm not sure what that is... looks more like Lt.Col. oak leaf insignia, but that's not usually in the case with a medal.

Comment: @J... A fair point, hmmm...

Comment: But it really, *really* looks like a bronze star. Ex: https://www.vanguardmil.com/products/bronze-star-medal-presentation-set. I have no idea what the device above it is, but it looks an awful lot like a major's or lt. colonel's oak leaves.

Comment: @RBarryYoung Agreed it's the bronze star...nothing else looks like that at all.  Major's oak leaf is gold - that's definitely silver.  Still not sure what it's doing in the frame, though.

Comment: First source is dead (and no Wayback Machine for it). Got another maybe?

Answer (score 10):

User Seldini on [Gateworld.Com](https://forum.gateworld.net/threads/33373-Jack-O-Neill-s-ribbons-and-medals) identified the [medals and stripes](https://web.archive.org/web/20050219225806/http://www.af.mil/news/airman/0104/af_awards_decorb.jpg) thusly;

> [Defense Distinguished Service Medal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defense_Distinguished_Service_Medal)
>   [Air Force Distinguished Service Medal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Air_Force_Distinguished_Service_Medal)
>   [Defense Superior Service Medal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defense_Superior_Service_Medal)
>   [Airman's Medal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airman%27s_Medal)
>   Defense Meritorious Service Medal
>   Meritorious Service Medal
>   Air Medal
>   Aerial Achievement Medal
>   Joint Service Commendation Medal
>   Air Force Commendation Medal
>   Air Force Achievement Medal
>   Outstanding Unit Award
>   Combat Readiness Medal
>   National Defense Service Medal
>   Vietnam Service Medal
>   Southwest Asia Service Medal
>   Air Force Overseas Long Tour
>   Longevity Service Award
>   Republic of Vietnam Campaign Medal
>   Kuwait Liberation Medal (Saudi Arabia)

The silver badge at the top is the '[Master Parachutists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parachutist_Badge_(United_States)#Master_Parachutist_Badge)' badge. The silver badge below is the US '[Command Space Operations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_and_Missile_Badge)' Badge

Jack O'Neill also has a Purple Heart (presumably multiples, given that he gets shot almost weekly) on the mantlepiece in his house.

Comment: Well that was quick and easy.